# Forecasting air passengers, but taking tickets sold into account

Tags: forecasting

The most classic forecasting example seems to be something like: given historic data on the number of air passengers for each month up until say December 1959, predict the number of air passengers for each month of 1960 ([example](http://rstudio-pubs-static.s3.amazonaws.com/311446_08b00d63cc794e158b1f4763eb70d43a.html)).

However, realistically, if one were actually to predict this, then:

- for January 1960, they'd already have received a lot of ticket bookings
- for February 1960, they'd already have received some ticket bookings
  ...
- for December 1960, they'd probably not yet have received any ticket bookings.

And so, surely they're want to use this information to adjust their forecasts?

How would one incorporate that information? Is there a literature on this, and what's it called? I'm confused by how none of the forecasting examples I can find make any mention of this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not limited to univariate models for forecasting. There are many multivariate models that can be used to include such information. For example, you could use [regression with ARIMA errors](https://otexts.com/fpp3/regarima.html)

$$
\mathsf{passengers}_t = \beta_0 + \beta_1 \mathsf{\text{tickets_sold}}_t + \eta_t
$$

where $\eta_t$ are the errors modeled using ARIMA model. It is a very simple model where we assume that some fraction of tickets sold $\beta_1$ for the flights at time $t$ translates to the number of passengers that will fly, where the variability not explained by the number of sold tickets is modeled using ARIMA.

Comment: Sure, but if `\eta_t` is large, then wouldn't this still result in large forecast errors? If e.g. we're close to the end of January 1960, and we want to forecast the total number of flights for January 1960, then just looking at `tickets_sold` should be quite accurate. However, if `\eta_t` is large, then wouldn't the formula above give a less accurate than possible prediction? I'll try coming up with some simulated data to illustrate what I mean

Comment: @ignoring_gravity forecast error would be large if the model would not be able to approximate the data well. If ARIMA wouldn't be a good model for the errors, then yes, it would not work. But how large $\eta_t$ would be would depend on how well does $\beta_0 + \beta_1 \mathsf{\text{tickets_sold}}_t $ model the data. No reason why a priori we could assume that the errors would be big or small knowing nothing about the data.